# Build works on local but fails on codemagic | Execution failed for task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols'

Tags: flutter, continuous-deployment, cicd, codemagic

I'm trying to implement a continuous deployment system to build my app and deploy to Google Play using codemagic. Doing a build works fine locally but fails remotely on codemagic.

Error summary:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command '/usr/local/share/android-sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip''
```

Complete log:

```
== Building for Android ==

> flutter build appbundle --debug
Running "flutter pub get" in My_Project...                     1,655ms

 Building with sound null safety 

Running Gradle task 'bundleDebug'...                            
[flutter_background_geolocation] Purging debug resources in release build
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/builder/programs/flutter_2_5_3/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geocoding-2.0.1/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/geocoding/GeocodingPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command '/usr/local/share/android-sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip''


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 19s
Running Gradle task 'bundleDebug'...                              141.1s
Gradle task bundleDebug failed with exit code 1


Build failed :|
Failed to build for Android
```

Current configuration on codemagic:

```
Flutter channel: stable 
Mode: debug 
Build for: Android
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

to fix this you need to upgrade Gradle version in `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` to 6.7.1 or commit gradle wrapper to your repository if you don't have this file.

Additional to that you also might need to upgrade Android Gradle plugin in `andriod/build.gradle`

```
- classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'
+ classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
```

**WITHOUT GRADLE UPGRADE**

if for some reasons you can't upgrade Gradle version you can freeze previous NDK version.

For that you can specify `ndkVersion "22.1.7171670"` in your build.gradle and make sure you use Java 1.8 since there is an issue with using latest Java versions.

In Codemagic you can specify Java version in `environment` section in your `codemagic.yaml` like this

```
workflows:
  workflow-name:
    environment:
      ndk: r22b
      java: 1.8
```

Comment: I updated the version to 6.7.1 and I have made sure that the `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file is in my github repository. But it is still not working, with the same problem

Comment: try to upgrade android plugin in `android/build.gradle`

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'` instead of 
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'`

Comment: This solved my problem, the app is now building on codemagic. Thank you so much!